# Neo4j Export database using dump in windows

Tags: shell, neo4j

I'm new to Neo4j and I found a couple of posts regarding dump but they use something called neo4j-shell that is not present in my installation.
I have a cypher-shell.bat that opens a shell that can be the right one but the problem is that the dump command used in the samples when executed does nothing, and I haven't found also any command to quit the shell.
If you have any clue on how to create a dump of the whole database it will be appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In general, answers to questions like this can be found by searching the [Neo4j documentation](https://neo4j.com/docs/) (make sure you're reading the version of the manual corresponding to your version of Neo4j). In this case, [section 10.3 of the operations manual](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/tools/dump-load/) for version 3.1 of Neo4j explains:

> A Neo4j database can be dumped and loaded using the `dump` and `load` commands of `neo4j-admin`

e.g.
`neo4j-admin dump --database=<database> --to=<destination-path>`

Like the `cypher-shell`, `neo4j-admin` is, by default, located in the "bin" folder of your neo4j installation.

FYI: `neo4j-shell` was deprecated and replaced by `cypher-shell`.

Comment: where is bin folder in windows? It does not exist. I installed neo4j desktop and an example neo4j database and searching for hours to load this database. It should have been as simple is a drag and drop

Comment: @canbax sorry, I'm not sure. I use macos & linux.

Comment: @canbax the `bin` folder exists for each `Project`. This should look like `C:/Users/user/.Neo4jDesktop\neo4jDatabases/database-0e23c195-05ae-472d-a0fa-6813a377a19f/installation-3.5.14/bin/`

Comment: @csaladenes I learned it a long time ago but still thank you, maybe it helps to others